# Blank Page after switching to UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to switch my `UIPageViewController`'s transition style from `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`.

When using `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl`, Pages transition as desired. However, with `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`, blank pages mysteriously appear between page turns. The pattern with which blank pages show isn't consistent between builds.

Any idea what might be happening here? I'm stumped.

```
//AppDelegate.m
PageVC *pageVC = [[PageVC alloc] 
initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal 
options:NULL];

//PageVC.h
@interface PageVC : UIPageViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource>

//PageVC.m
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.graphVC = [[GraphVC alloc]init];
    self.aboutVC = [[AboutVC alloc] init];
    self.exerciseVC = [[ExerciseVC alloc] init];
    self.viewControllerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.exerciseVC, self.graphVC, self.aboutVC, nil];

    self.currentPage = 1;
    if (self.graphVC != nil) {
        self.dataSource = self;

        [self setViewControllers:@[self.graphVC]
                       direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                        animated:NO
                      completion:NULL];  
    }}


- (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (self.currentPage >= 2) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        self.currentPage += 1;
        return [self.viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:self.currentPage];
    }
}

- (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (self.currentPage <= 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        self.currentPage -= 1;
        return [self.viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:self.currentPage];
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be unrelated, but beware using `viewControllerAfter...` and `viewControllerBefore...` to set your `currentPage`: the above two methods are called when you start to swipe, but if you swipe back before completing, the VC on screen will revert, but your currentPage will have been updated.  I would use the delegate method, `didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers:transitionCompleted:`, to set your `currentPage` only if the `transitionCompleted` is true.

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf. That was indeed part of the problem.

Sidenote: This question was downvoted right after posting. I realize that someone actually spent karma on that, and so there was probably something wrong about it. Can anyone elaborate, so that I know how to write better future posts?

Comment: The up-/down-vote breakdown currently shows 0 of each, so whoever downvoted must have reversed themselves.  To my mind your question was fine.  Nice solution below, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pbasdf worote, tracking `currentPage` in `viewControllerAfter`/`Before` was a bad idea. When using `TransitionStyleScroll`, these two methods are called  multiple times per page turn.  As a result, they sometimes incremented incorrectly and returned nil. (`TransitionStylePageCurl` only calls each method once, after a page turn.)

A better solution is to check for the `viewController` passed to each method, and return before and after accordingly:

```
// PageVC.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // initialize array of ViewControllers
    viewControllerArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:exerciseVC, graphVC, aboutVC, nil];
}

- (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [viewControllerArray indexOfObject:viewController];
    if (index >= [viewControllerArray count]-1) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:index+1];
    }
}

- (UIViewController *) pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [viewControllerArray indexOfObject:viewController];
    if (index <= 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [viewControllerArray objectAtIndex:index-1];
    }
```

Comment: I had this exact same problem, except I wasn't using the PageCurl Transition Style.  But my ViewControllers were really complex, so  tracking tracking `currentPage` in `viewControllerAfter/Before` was a bad idea for me as well because of the slow load time. Using your `[viewControllerArray indexOfObject:viewController]` fixed it though!